# Relational Mapper for C# that keeps the relational model

Tags: c#, haskell, orm, ado.net, dsl

Currently my Application uses ADO.Net and manual mapping of the results.

The reasons for that are:

- many ORMs seem to have rather unpredictable side-effects with lazy loading
- ORMs do not give a developer the power SQL can provide
- I dislike code thats generated in a build-step

The approach to do things by hand has proven rather (too) tedious, but I was not able to find an ORM that solves these problems for C#.

A promising appoach seems to be to map SQL to the programming language used (make an EDSL for database access).

I found several of those projects in haskell:

- [opaleye](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye)
- [haskelldb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb)
- esqueleto

Those projects also can add type saftey to id columns, so you cannot make a join on columns that are not actually related.

Are there similar projects for C# that are still developed and allow POCOs (or otherwise unit-testable design)?

Comment: Have you tried [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).  It's a micro ORM that basically gets rid of a lot of the boiler plate code you end up writing with ADO.Net.

Comment: Yep, my vote for Dapper, there where you need a lightweight microORM Dapper is the beast you're looking for. Else, if you need more complex things then just go for Linq and ADO entities.